# Theoretical: Implementing MSMQ using SSL to send message

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have to create a demo app (desktop application) which send messages from modules (within one application) using `SSL`. I thought about using `MSMQ` is it possible to do so? I cannot find any documentation or tutorial about it.

If such solution is impossible to implement can anyone redirect me to link which describe how can I create `SSL tunneling` for messages within one application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSMQ directly provides HTTPS support

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms707036(v=vs.85).aspx

You can configure an HTTPS endpoint for MSMQ and call that endpoint from your desktop application.

Comment: Can't believe i did miss this article. Thank you Eric.

Comment: Glad to help.  Sometimes easy to over-think these things :-)